# Equivariant cohomology of symmetric group acting on a product

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, equivariant-cohomology

Let $X$ be a finite CW-complex.  The symmetric group $S_n$ acts on the product $X^{\times n}$ in the obvious way.  Let $H^{\bullet}_{S_n}(X^{\times n})$ be the (Borel) equivariant cohomology of this action, that is, the cohomology of the Borel construction
$$X^{\times n} \times_{S_n} ES_n = \left(X^{\times n} \times ES_n\right)/S_n,$$
where $E S_n$ is a contractible CW complex on which $S_n$ acts freely.

**Question**: How can $H^{\bullet}_{S_n}(X^{\times n})$ be expressed in terms of the topology of $X$?  I've written the question with $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients, but I'm also interested in the case of coefficients in a finite field.

Comment: The cohomology of such objects is closely related to Dyer-Lashoff operations. If you consider all $n$ at once, you have formed the free $E_\infty$ algebra on $X$. The cohomology of such things is calculated in Cohen, Lada, May. I really enjoy Lawson's exposition on it from [the handbook of homotopy theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.03889.pdf). See Theorem 5.5.